# Validate that string is the beginning of a regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I can successfully validate a complete Canadian zip code (like `"M1B0A1"`) but how can I validate that a string can be an incomplete Canadian zip (like `"M1B"`)?  I want to check that the existing content could match a regex if more characters are typed later.  As soon as the user enters a string that cannot possibly be the start of a Canadian zip, I'd like to show an error.

My existing regex for validating a *complete* Canadian zip is:

```
^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ] ?\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d$
```

I tried to modify the regex by making each character optional with this regex:

```
^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]?\d?[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]? ?\d?[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]?\d?$
```

but then that incorrectly accepts string like `"777"` or `"HA16"`.  Can I do this with regex, or am I going to have to create a set of regexes of varying string length?  I'd rather avoid something like

```
switch(str.length) {
    case 1:
        return /[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]/.test(str);
    case 2:
        return /[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d/.test(str);
    //.... and more
}
```

Comment: Your initial regex is invalid. Is it `^([ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]) ?(\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d)$`? You can even write it as `^([A-CEGHJ-NPR-TVXY]\d[A-CEGHJ-NPR-TV-Z]) ?(\d[A-CEGHJ-NPR-TV-Z]\d)$`

Comment: I'd like to know the reasoning behind avoiding the switch statement, which results in readable code, and opting for the unmaintainable regex spaghetti?

Comment: Yes, this is quite unreadable (although you can put the alternatives on different lines and define blocks and then build the pattern with RegExp constructor, but still...): [`^([A-CEGHJ-NPR-TVXY]|[A-CEGHJ-NPR-TVXY]\d|[A-CEGHJ-NPR-TVXY]\d[A-CEGHJ-NPR-TV-Z]|[A-CEGHJ-NPR-TVXY]\d[A-CEGHJ-NPR-TV-Z] |[A-CEGHJ-NPR-TVXY]\d[A-CEGHJ-NPR-TV-Z] ?\d|[A-CEGHJ-NPR-TVXY]\d[A-CEGHJ-NPR-TV-Z] ?\d[A-CEGHJ-NPR-TV-Z]|[A-CEGHJ-NPR-TVXY]\d[A-CEGHJ-NPR-TV-Z] ?\d[A-CEGHJ-NPR-TV-Z]\d)$`](https://regex101.com/r/eG9nK7/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that was a typo.  I thought it was possible I was overlooks some feature of regex.  Another kinda janky idea I had was dynamically building out the regex piece by pieces based on my string length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1

I suppose you could use the 'OR' `|` and append each of the regex patterns from the `switch-case` list that you posted, that way the regex would practically do the work of the `switch-case` for you. **Edit**: the order of each `case` should be reversed, though, so as to match the most characters possible.

**Template**:

```
^(A|B|C|D|E|F)$
```

The letters should be replaced with the following

```
A: the complete regex pattern              (Case 6)
B: regex pattern for first 5 characters    (Case 5)
C: regex pattern for first 4 characters    (Case 4)
D: regex pattern for first 3 characters    (Case 3)
E: regex pattern for first 2 characters    (Case 2)
F: regex pattern for the first character   (Case 1)
```

The end result isn't pretty: [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pE2oZ9/1)

---

**Edit** [16-FEB-2016]

## Solution 2

To avoid typing out each of the cases, you could nest optional groups. Each group would represent the pattern of each zip code character so that when the first character is correctly matched then the next character will be optional; then if that character is matched then the next one would become optional, and so on.
*(This might be what you were attempting to do in your second regex pattern)*.

**Template**:

```
^(A(B(C(D(E(F)?)?)?)?)?)$
```

The letters should be replaced as follows

```
A: regex pattern for the 1st zip code character   
B: regex pattern for the 2nd zip code character
C: regex pattern for the 3rd zip code character
D: regex pattern for the 4th zip code character
E: regex pattern for the 5th zip code character
F: regex pattern for the 6th zip code character
```

**Result** ([DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yP6uG2/1))

```
^(\[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY\](\d(\[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ\]( ?(\d(\[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ\](\d)?)?)?)?)?)?)$
```

Additionally, if you're not interested in the captured groups then you could modify the above to use non-capturing groups: [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lM4nL1/1). It's your call.

Comment: Yes.  Solution 2 was what I was looking for at the time.  I've since decided to reevaluate my validation logic, but that was what I wanted.  A way to tack on extra optional characters.

Answer (score -1):

I changed your regex to `^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY](?:(?:\d$)|(?:\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]$)|(?:\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d$)|(?:\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]$)|(?:\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d$))?$`

Basically it divides the following regex `^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d$` into 6 parts, which is each digit, than I make the first one obrigatory and the following ones optional, making sure the order you want, that is, if one digit is skipped it will accept if that is the end of the string or fail if there is more digits after the skipped one.

I think this is what you want, here is a [regex101 test](https://regex101.com/r/qZ5mQ2/2).

Comment: @ryanyuyu What do you consider a incomplete canadian zip? Anything at least 1 character long?

Comment: Yes.  Anything between 1 and 6 characters.  Any string that could, if the right characters were added to it, still be a valid zip.  As a lot of the comments have suggested, using either regex alternative `|` or just javascript logic is necessary.

Comment: @ryanyuyu just edited the regex, check again please.

Comment: How is this different from [Mr.Z's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35371430/4320665)?  It still seems to require typing out all 6 alternatives.

Comment: @ryanyuyu it aint, but it works, its just one regex. Does it have to be pretty? End user ain't gonna look at it, and for future maintenance you can comment to clarify it.